# How to view current and past thread counts of an Azure App Service?

Tags: azure

I'm trying to find the metric data for the current 'thread count' of an [Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/) using the Azure web interface.   I've think I've seen this metric before in past iterations of the Azure interface, I could be wrong, but I'm not sure how to navigate to in the latest Azure web interface.   There are quite a few different widgets and pages connected to application insights and other metric recorders, but I can't seem to be able to locate the 'Thread Count'.

[image: small screenshot of latest azure]

I've seen some examples of how to do this programmatically, but I'm not sure how to do it with the latest web interface.

What is the simplest way to view the current thread count and/or thread counts for the last 24 hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go to the ***Diagnose and solve problems*** tab and click ***Metrics per instance (Apps)*** in the sidebar of that tab.

[image]

In that area you can then select a thread count metric.